# How to make xpathSApply output vector of length nodes using xmlValue?

Tags: r, xpath

Lets say I have following:

```
library(XML)    

my.xml <- '
<tv>
  <show>
    <name>Star Trek TNG</name>
    <rating>1.0</rating>
  </show>
  <show>
    <name>Doctor Who</name>
  </show>
  <show>
    <name>Babylon 5</name>
    <rating>2.0</rating>
  </show>
</tv>
'

doc <- xmlParse(my.xml)
xpathSApply(doc, "/tv/show/rating", xmlValue)

# [1] "1.0" "2.0"
```

There are three 'show' nodes. How can I instead make the output be:

```
# [1] "1.0" NULL "2.0"
```

so as to account for Doctor Who not having a rating in the xml but the length still being 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you supply the path all the way to 'rating', the node list will already only have the 2 elements to begin with. So when you apply `xmlValue()` to this node list, the output will also only have 2 elements. You can get around this by just starting from one level up in the tree:

```
> xpathSApply(doc, '/tv/show', function(x) xmlValue(xmlChildren(x)$rating))
[1] "1.0" NA    "2.0"
```