# How to make xpathSApply output vector of length nodes using xmlAttrs?

Tags: xml, r, xpath

This is a follow up to [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039086/how-to-make-xpathsapply-output-vector-of-length-nodes) I have already asked but this time I'm trying to get xmlAttrs instead of xmlValue. So let's say we have the following:

```
my.xml <- '
<tv>
  <show>
    <name>Star Trek TNG</name>
    <rating>1.0</rating>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
  </show>
  <show>
    <name>Doctor Who</name>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
  </show>
  <show>
    <name>Babylon 5</name>
    <rating>2.0</rating>
  </show>
</tv>
'
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse(my.xml)
xpathSApply(doc, '/tv/show', function(x) xmlValue(xmlChildren(x)$a))
# [1] "google" "google" NA
```

I would rather the output to be

```
# [1] "http://www.google.com" "http://www.google.com" NA
```

However I just can't figure it out. I was thinking it might be something like this, but I was a wrong:

```
xpathSApply(doc, '/tv/show', function(x) xmlAttrs(xmlChildren(x)$a))
# Error in UseMethod("xmlAttrs", node) : 
# no applicable method for 'xmlAttrs' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

The closest I have gotten is this:

```
xpathSApply(doc, '/tv/show', function(x) xmlChildren(x)$a)
# [[1]]
# <a href="http://wwww.google.com">google</a> 
#
# [[2]]
# <a href="http://wwww.google.com">google</a> 
#
# [[3]]
# NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost got it. You just have to take care of the NULL case, yourself, since `xmlAttrs()` is giving you that error when it encounters the NULL:

```
> xpathSApply(doc, '/tv/show', function(x) ifelse(is.null(xmlChildren(x)$a), NA, xmlAttrs(xmlChildren(x)$a, 'href')))
[1] "http://www.google.com" "http://www.google.com" NA
```